# placement new overloaded but no compilation errors when overloaded new function is not provided

Tags: c++

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <cstdint>

  class TestMemoryPool {
      public:
          void Init(uint8_t* buf, size_t size) {}

          TestMemoryPool(uint8_t* buf, int size) {}

          TestMemoryPool* Instance() { return m_pInstance;}

          void* Alloc(int size, uint8_t alignment) { return nullptr;}

          void* Alloc(int size) {return nullptr;}                                                                                                                   

          TestMemoryPool() {}                                                                                                                                       

      private:                                                                                                                                                      
          TestMemoryPool(TestMemoryPool const&){};                                                                                                                  
          TestMemoryPool& operator=(TestMemoryPool const&);                                                                                                         
          static TestMemoryPool* m_pInstance;   
  };                                                                                                                                                                

  #if 0                                                                                                                                                             
  void* operator new(size_t n, TestMemoryPool* pool)                                                                                                                
  {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      if(pool !=NULL)                                                                                                                                               
      {                                                                                                                                                             
          return pool->Alloc(n, 8);                                                                                                                                 
      }                                                                                                                                                             
  }                                                                                                                                                                 

  void* operator new[](size_t n , TestMemoryPool* pool)                                                                                                             
  {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      if(pool !=NULL)                                                                                                                                               
      {                                                                                                                                                             
          return pool->Alloc(n, 8);                                                                                                                                 
      }                                                                                                                                                             
  }                                                                                                                                                                 

  void operator delete(void* ptr, TestMemoryPool* pool) {}
  void operator delete[](void* ptr , TestMemoryPool* pool) {}
  #endif

  int main()
  {
      uint8_t FIXED_DYNAMIC_MEMORY_BUFFER[5*1024*1024];
      TestMemoryPool gDynamicMemPool(FIXED_DYNAMIC_MEMORY_BUFFER, FIXED_DYNAMIC_MEMORY_BYTES);
      TestMemoryPool *m_Pool = gDynamicMemPool.Instance();
      uint8_t *m_testArena = new (m_Pool) uint8_t[2];
      return 0;
 }
```

Currently if you compile this code it will compile without any issues even though intention is to use overloaded new function which should return the allocated memory. Is there any way to raise a compilation error when below is done:

```
 datatype *x= new (allocatedpool) datatype[bytes]
```

Intention is that sometime the library users forget to include the corresponding .h file which will cause it to compile without raising any issues but at runtime it will crash because it didn't allocate the memory from the preallocated pool.

Also, don't want to use any fancy template to do this as it is a memory constrained embedded device.

Comment: https://ideone.com/gzc3ZH seems to solve the problem, but want to use the pointers.

Comment: You could also consider more member functions `m_Pool->Alloc<uint8_t>(2)`

Comment: Where's the problem of defining `TestMemoryPool` and the overloads of `new` and `delete` in the same header? When you have access to `TestMemoryPool` your overloads will also be around.

Comment: @StefanKssmr that is not true, in this example they are around but they may not be in a single file. So you can still compile with TestMemoryPool without overloading new with custom allocater

Comment: @user3053970 I got this, I was just wandering why you don't design the library such that they are in the same file if you are afraid that someone forgets to include the header with the overloads? Maybe there are good reasons not to do it, I just want to make sure you considered that option.

Comment: "use fancy ... template" does not necessarily imply "use lots of memory". Properly written templates can reduce memory usage.

Comment: @PeteBecker: so how to do that?